# PHP how to flatten out this indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ContractorName] => Joe Soap
            [BonusAmount] => 73.92
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ContractorName] => Mike Michaels
            [BonusAmount] => 68.55
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ContractorName] => John Smith
            [BonusAmount] => 34.35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ContractorName] => Pete Peterson
            [BonusAmount] => 24.61
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ContractorName] => Pete Smith
            [BonusAmount] => 22.76
        )

)
```

How do I go about ending up with an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Joe Soap] => 73.92
    [Mike Michaels] => 68.55
    [John Smith] => 34.35
    [Pete Peterson] => 24.61
    [Pete Smith] => 22.76
)
```

I'm a bit lost at the moment.  I have tried creating a new array by looping over the first array, but I'm getting unwanted results.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A mix of [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) and [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through entire array using `foreach` and then use each piece to construct new array.

```
$out = [];
foreach ($inputArray as $v) {
    $out[$v['ContractorName']] = $v['BonusAmount'];
}
```

---

Second solution is by using `array_combine` and `array_column`.

```
$keys = array_column($inputArray, 'ContractorName');
$values = array_column($inputArray, 'BonusAmount');

$output = array_combine($keys, $values);

//Or put everything in single line
$output = array_combine(array_column($inputArray, 'ContractorName'), array_column($inputArray, 'BonusAmount'));
```

---

Third option

```
$output = array_column($inputArray, 'BonusAmount', 'ContractorName');
```

Comment: Perfect.  Works like a charm.  Will give upvote and kudos in a few minutes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_combine` with `array_column` as

```
array_combine(array_column($records, 'ContractorName'),array_column($records, 'BonusAmount'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one array_column(), and with the third parameter to specify the index.  [**Live Demo.**](https://eval.in/814744)

```
array_column($array, 'BonusAmount', 'ContractorName');
```